# C# MVC3 Listbox callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, callback, listbox

I am creating a `ListBox` in MVC:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItemIds, new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"))
```

which works fine, I can see the `ListBox` appear in the view.

I want to add some kind of callback when a user clicks and selects an item in the list. How can I do this using MVC3?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best served by adding an id parameter to your ListBox, and then doing whatever callback that you want by using jQuery. Your line of code would then be like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItemIds, new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"), new {id = "MyListBox")
```

Afterwards you could easily hook up an event in jQuery as follows:

```
$('#MyListBox').change(function() { ...some function... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript onChange handler with this overload:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItemIds, new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"), new{onchange="onListBoxChanged(); return false;"})
```

where onListBoxChanged() is javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
@using(html.begainform( ........your action name........))
{
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedItemIds, new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text"))
}
```

& in jquery you can write something like this

```
   $("<Id or class of your ListBox>").change(function() {
        this.form.submit();
   });
```